# How to create diferent startups for diferent builds of mvc web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mocking

I need to build a slight different version of my MVC service for the purpose of testing.

The idea is to mock certain services, like authentication, at startup, without adding code to the main version. 
To prevent deploying any test code, all test code is located on a file, and prevented from being compiled into main version using compile directives.

So, to keep all things separated i need a way to hook into the startup without actually write code in the standard startup classes of MVC.
How can it do this, but keeping my main version code clean?

As asked an simple example of what i want to do:

```
#if MOCK //code only included into mock build type

namespace MyService.MockBuild
{
    public class ServiceFactoryMock : ServiceFactory
    {
        //prepare mocked versions of the services
        ...
    }

    public class MockService
    {
        //this is what needs to be done at startup, from here
        public static void MockTheServer()
        {
            global.serviceFactory = new ServiceFactoryMock();        
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Show a [mcve] that help clarify exactly what it is you are asking

Comment: Something seems off about your current design, which is why I asked for an example. having to build a different version of your service for the purpose of testing is a code smell. Need to see an example of what you are trying to test and how you have tried to test it so far and where the problem occurs.

Comment: The version only different in what is needed, the authentication service. My authentication service abstracts the real authentication service that is a third party cloud based service. The only way to automate tests is mocking this service.Mocking is widely used in testing. Also, you can  check Factory Pattern and Dependency injection for the purpose of testing.

The purpose of my question is to avoid adding smelly code in the files used for the main build.

Comment: So it sounds like dependency injection is the solution for this? Potentially controlled with config, which of course can be different for each build.

Comment: Yes, dependency injection is the way to alter the behavior of an dependency from a different build. This means the main build is clean of all test code. I don't see how config can fire execution of my MockService class. Normally i find a way to hook into the start code, but i don't see how in this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is by registering PreApplicationStartMethod

```
#if MOCK
//only registered if inside MOCK build type.
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MockInitializer), "Initialize")]
namespace MChatServer.MockBuild
{
    public class MockInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            //Inject all the mocked dependencies through mocked service factory
            global.serviceFactory = new ServiceFactoryMock();
        }
    }
...
}
#end
```

Regards this his an acceptable way for me, there are more complete ways to customize the asp.net builds as suggested [here](https://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx/).